# nginx load balance upstream hash using custom header

Tags: nginx

We can create an upstream block using a hash of `$request_uri`  as below

```
upstream backend {
    hash $request_uri consistent;
    server backend1.example.com;
    server backend2.example.com;
}
```

Can we use a custom header for this hash instead of request_uri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nginx uses the pattern

`$http_{header_lowercased_with_underscores}`

for headers.  So for example you can use the following to feed custom header `X-My-Custom-Header` to the hash

```
upstream backend {
  hash $http_x_my_custom_header consistent;
  server backend1.example.com;
  server backend2.example.com;
}
```

Source: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_